# Change View Layout Based on Device

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a plugin to detect mobile view or desktop view. I need to be able to change my view layout based on either the user is view from a mobile device or desktop.

I tried to control the logic  in Zend_Controller_Plugin Abstract Class in `dispatchLoopStartUp()` method and also in the bootstrap method `_initLayoutName()` but I still couldn't achieve the result.

Find the below snippet of what i expected to achieve

```
public function checkDetectDevice() {
      $detect = new My_MobileDetect();
      if($device->isMobile()) {
          //Change View Layout. 
      }
}
```

Can someone help me on how to achieve view layout changing in Zend v1

Comment: Why dont you use bootstrap or any other frontend framework?

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola yes I use bootstrap, but I dont need the resposive design from CSS bootstrap

Comment: try this $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('yourlayout'); //yourlayout.phtml

Answer (score 0):

To change the layout in a plugin, try this:

```
Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout('your_layout'); // for your_layout.phtml
```